# Openshift 502 Proxy Error and exit signal Segmentation fault (11) in logs

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, openshift

I'm running a Wordpress website with the Avada `theme (v3.8.8)` on OpenShift (Bronze plan but not paying anything yet..) and cannot update anymore. Can't update to `Wordpress 4.4` nor can I update the Avada theme to `v3.9.1`. Normal operation of the webapp is OK. The Wordpress site was created using Quickstart and the site and database are running on 1 gear.

When I try to update via the Wordpress admin console I receive a 502 Proxy error and my application crashes. Only way to recover the site is to reboot it via the OpenShift admin console.

I've looked up the logs and am seeing the following:

About 8 Segmentation fault messages `(but no coredump in /var/lib/)`:

```
child pid 286229 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /var/lib/
```

And at the end a warning:

```
[notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
WARNING: MaxClients of 60 exceeds ServerLimit value of 17 servers,
 lowering MaxClients to 17.  To increase, please see the ServerLimit
 directive.
```

I tried increasing the MySQL max connections by setting the environment variable `OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_MAX_CONNECTIONS (https://forums.openshift.com/maxclients-and-503-help)` but this didn't work.

Openshift won't let me see or edit the HTTPD configuration and I'm running out of options. Can't file a issue with Openshift because that's only allowed starting from the Silver plan.

Hope someone can help me resolve this issue or point me in the right direction.

Comment: That is a pure Apache warning. Go into the apache configuration and change the settings there.

Comment: Sadly Openshift won't let me change the apache configuration (permission denied) to get rid of the warning. But because it's a warning, would you expect it to resolve my update issue / crashing the app?

Comment: Signal 11 is (one of) the most serious errors you can get signaling either complete software failure or even hardware error. If you can not alter the MaxClients or ServerLimit to test if the situation changes, then you can only change your application to reduce the number of connections the browser makes with apache. However this will fail quickly again once you have multiple people accessing the browser. I would test it on a local system to see if you can reproduce it, and where you can change the settings and go from there.

Comment: I've been looking somewhat deeper (into a snapshot of the app) and saw that the MaxClients and ServerLimit is set by a computation based on the max amount of gear memory. I cannot change this. So perhaps that's not the way to tackle this issue, it's a warning after all and not an error. Reproducing it locally would be a hell of a job, keeping in mind that OpenShift sets all kinds of settings based on environment variables that are not directly visible to me (users). If I would get it all running at all. Isn't there any other way to pinpoint where the Signal 11 errors are coming from?

Comment: It sometimes creates coredumps. Google Sig 11. It is about the worst you can get :)

Comment: I've seen it on Google.... just my luck :-(

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know exactly how and why, but I was able to upgrade the Avada theme and Wordpress by doing the following:

- Disable WordFence (apparently WordFence is taking up a lot of resources)
- Restart the app (rhc app-restart [appname])
- Immediately after the app has restarted, issue an update via the WordPress GUI. First I updated the Avada Theme. Then restarted the app, and immediately updated WordPress
- Enabled WordFence again (by restarting the app immediately followed by enabling the WordFence plugin)

I guess the signal 11 errors are somehow related to a lack of resources. The WordPress GUI also takes up a lot (about 100MB). Still I could not see that the limit of my gear was reached memory wise (hitting the 512MB boundary) which could have been an indicator of the signal 11 errors. However, retrieving the memory failcount I see that there have been 78306 hits. Guessing that's not a good figure, should be zero!

A very useful item on the OpenShift forum showed me how to display the memory usage f.i. The forum item displays commands for information to better understand OpenShift gears in my application. See https://forums.openshift.com/how-to-check-actual-physical-parameters-of-your-gear

My problem has been solved for now, but I'm sure I'll be hitting the fence somewhere in the near future :-(. @Norbert: Thanks for taking the time to respond on my issue.